# Creating a Pax Wicket (Blueprint) application

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, wicket-1.5, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

It's still a request: [Maven Archetype for Pax Wicket (Blueprint)](http://team.ops4j.org/browse/PAXWICKET-234)

I'd like to know what's the fastest way to generate a Pax Wicket - Blueprint application (or how to convert an existing Wicket application into Pax Wicket Blueprint)

The only option I see is to download the samples and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a Blueprint archetype for Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/2.2.5/developers-guide/archetypes.html) and adding Pax Wicket dependencies to the pom.xml is so far the fastest way to create a skeleton Pax Wicket app.

And [here's](https://github.com/akiwarheit/KeeboisAdventures/blob/master/KeeboisAdventures.md) how I did it.

Comment: also, i've managed to create an archetype for it. will be releasing it sometime this week.